# Buscar por numero con mongoose node.js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy tratando de buscar por numero usando mongoose. Basicamente e creado un campo dentro de la coleccion llamado `iduser` este al registrar desde la consola de mongodb le inserto numeros como 1, 2 o cualquier otro excepto un `ObjectId.` Estoy realizando pruebas y lo ideal seria usar ObjectId o algo asi 12kj1jkj312j3lk1. Este es el error:

```
{
  "error": "Cast to Number failed for value \"{ iduser: '1' }\" at path \"iduser\" for model \"Task\""
}
```

Modelo tareas:

```
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    status:{
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 1
    },
    iduser:{
        //mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 254
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema, "Task")
```

Trato de buscar por `userid` de la siguiente manera:

```
router.get('/mytasks', async (req, res) => {
    const iduser = req.query.iduser;
    try{
        const result = await Task.find({iduser: iduser})
            return res.send(result)
    
        }catch(error){
            return res.send({error: error.message})
        }

});
```

Pero obtengo el error de arriba. La verdad no se por que no me deja si es una base de datos que debe de permitirme buscar por cualquier campo de mi colección.

Asi esta mi colección:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: por que creas un `iduser` y no usas el _id que te facilita mongoDB?

Comment: Basicamente e estado registrando tareas, con el iduser supongo que un admin le asigna tareas a un usuario y para no crear una coleccion de usuarios estoy insertando esos id que hacen referencia como supuestos id usuarios. Podria hacerlo pero para probar la aplicacion desde un cliente rest uso esos numeros es solo para probar una prueba de concepto

Comment: me parece un desperdicio, a gran escala tu db estaria con muchos campos innecesarios, además, en los datos que muestras por consola tienes id´s repetidos, y eso haria que al buscar datos en concreto tenga varios errores

Comment: Deberia de tener una colección Usuarios y dentro de esa colección un objeto Tareas[] eso seria lo optimo?

Comment: es una opción desde mi punto de vista bastante factible, cuando pides al backend datos del usuario también te traes sus tareas, todo en un solo endpoint

Comment: Si tienes razón. Lo que intento demostrar luego ya con esto solucionado es que cuando se inserte una nueva tarea para un usuario con un id determinado "hacer que el servidor le mande una notificación" en tiempo real. Al inicio tengo pensado que el usuario obtenga sus tareas consultando este endpoint pero luego vera notificaciones.. no lo voy hacer con websockets hay otra alternativa y ya la tengo.

Comment: tengo curiosidad de saber como vas a enviar notificaciones en tiempo real sin usar websockets, es interesante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta parte del error `\"{ iduser: '1' }\"` se ve que el numero 1 es un string, y tu en el modelo de tienes como `Number`, prueba haciendo esto:

```
router.get('/mytasks', async (req, res) => {
const {iduser} = req.query;
try{
    const result = await Task.find({iduser: Number(iduser)})
        return res.status(200).send(result)

    }catch(error){
        return res.status(400).send({error: error.message})
    }

});
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero sigo obteniendo el error: ` "Cast to Number failed for value \"{ iduser: '1' }\" at path \"iduser\" for model \"Task\""`

Comment: que te devuelve por consola `req.query`?

Comment: `console.log(req.query)` = { iduser: '1' } y `console.log(req.query.iduser)` = 1. E reiniciado el servidor pero lo e vuelto a reiniciar y ya funciona! Gracias por tu respuesta. Se que lo hago talvez no sea optimo pero como cualquier motor de base de datos deberia de permitir de buscar por cualquier campo. Gracias.

Comment: en absoluto, todos tenemos distintas formas de manejar datos dentro de la programación, si la app funciona, PERFECTO, si el código esta optimizado y es legible, MAS perfecto aun, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema y lo resolvi eliminando las comillas ('' or "") al hacer la solicitud `{ iduser: 1 }`.